# How to avoid crc16 collisions?

Tags: algorithm, hash, crc16

I am experiencing a pretty annoying issue, using a crc16 hash to manage some of my informations.

In my application, I pass some information into an url parameter, a huge encoded context. That context allow the users to recover their old searches. In that context, i have some elements I hash to be sure it won't take too much characters.

It seems that some elements return the same hash (crc16 algorithm).

I take the has and transform it to a string : crc.ToString("X4");
For example, two different elements gives me : 5A8E.

I tried to use a crc32, but if I do that, the old context won't be recognize.

Do you have any idea how i can find a solution to that ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Use a hash algorithm with less collisions and re-hash the data.

Comment: Yes, but if I do that, the old hashed values won't be recovered no ?

Comment: Why do you want to recover/keep them?

Comment: Cause users can save some urls with this context, and it has to work even if I do some changes.

Comment: CRC is _not_ a hash. It's a checksum, and it's unsuitable for use as a hash function.

Comment: @NickJohnson And it does indeed make for a decent checksum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even if CRC16 was an ideal hash function (which it's not), with just 16 bits, the [Birthday Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) means that there's around a 50% chance of a hash collision in a set of just 2^8 = 256 items.  You almost certainly need more bits.

You can't keep the old hashes working *and* make them distinguish existing collisions -- that's a contradiction.  But you can implement a new, better hashing scheme, add a flag to the URL parameters to indicate that you're using this new scheme, make sure that all your pages generate only these new-style URLs, and "grandfather in" the old-style URLs (which will continue to produce the same collisions as before).  I'd suggest giving users a big, bright message to update their bookmarks, and auto-redirecting the page, whenever you get an old-style URL.

Comment: Thank you j_random_hacker, that's a pretty good idea.

I will try yours.

Answer (score 0):

To explain the other solution i thought about and I am implementing.

I just prepare a crc32 and a crc16 hash for my elements. I use the 32 for the new urls i now build, but use the crc16 hash as a fallback for old urls.

So, when I try to compare the Hash, i start with the new Hash, and, if i can't find any element, i go to my fallback and compare it with the crc16 hash.

This allow me to get any case.

Comment: Is the new hash longer?  (If it's the same size, you'll just introduce more collisions for everyone -- old and new.)

Comment: Yes longer, new one is based on 8 characters :) 

And it currently works like a charm, waiting for the test team to finish their crazy tests :)

Comment: It still sounds like you're trying to use a hash to uniquely identify something. If the consequence of a hash collision is catastrophic, you probably shouldn't be using hashing - and you _definitely_ shouldn't be using short, non-cryptographically-secure hashes.